# Create date index while importing multiple csv from file names

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have 250 csv files in a folder, i used the following code to import them to a single dataframe:

```
files = "~/*.csv"
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, dtype='str') for f in glob.glob(files)], ignore_index=True)
```

My problem is i dont have date info inside any of the files, the date is mentioned in the filename like "`LSH_190207`" which is `7-Feb-2019`. 
Is there a way i can include this info in the dataframe while importing the files, preferably as index.
Or at least create a new column that would contain the file names, so i can later split & format it into date column.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can ,

Assuming the file list is

```
files = glob.glob('*.csv')
#['file1_LSH_190207_something.csv', 'file2_LSH_190208_something.csv']
#[f.split("_")[2] for f in files] gives ['190207', '190208']
```

This will create a date column with the value of date as string:

```
df= pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, dtype='str').assign(date= f.split("_")[2]) for f in files],\
                                                                  ignore_index=True)
```

*Sample Output:*

```
   A  B  C    date
0  1  2  3  190207
1  4  5  6  190207
2  5  6  8  190208
3  9  1  3  190208
```

Post this you could do the below to convert the date in your own format:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')

0    07-Feb-2019
1    08-Feb-2019
2    09-Feb-2019
```

Comment: The import worked, but my file names ended with .CSV after the date info, so I used df.date = df.date.str.replace('.csv', '') to just keep the numbers. The date conversion didn't work, I used df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%y%m%d')

Comment: show me a sample date please, if `190207` just use pd.to_datetime()

Answer (score 1):

Create `Datetimeindex` in lins comprehension and pass it to parameter `keys` in [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), only necessary removing second level of `MultiIndex` by `reset_index`:

```
idx = pd.to_datetime([f.split("_")[2] for f in files])
print (idx)

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, dtype='str') for f in files], 
                keys = idx).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
```