# Concaternate csv files into one data frame including file names as a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a folder with multiple scv files, each files is named as follows, 
Result_2007_01_16
Result_2007_01_17
......
Result_2014_07_30

basically I have a file for each business day from 2007, 
I am trying to append all files into one data frame and add the file name as a new column, since the files dont have the dates as a column within it self.

I found few lines of script in stackoverflow that helps to concaternate all files into one df, can someone help me to slightly edit this to include the filename as a new column.

This is the script I found to concaternate all files into one df.

```
  import glob

  import pandas as pd

  df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in glob.glob('my_file*.csv')])
```

Comment: try `df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f).assign(filename=f) for f in glob.glob('my_file*.csv')])`

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54613381/create-date-index-while-importing-multiple-csv-from-file-names/54613769?noredirect=1#comment96040862_54613769

Comment: Thanks @ALollz it works perfectly well.